# Removing a part of a URL with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, query-string

Removing the query string from a URL in Ruby could be done like this:

```
url.split('?')[0]
```

Where *url* is the complete URL including the query string (e.g. `url = http://www.domain.extension/folder?schnoo=schnok&foo=bar`).

Is there a faster way to do this, i.e. without using *split*, but rather using Rails?

**edit:** The goal is to redirect from `http://www.domain.extension/folder?schnoo=schnok&foo=bar` to `http://www.domain.extension/folder`.

**EDIT:** I used:

```
url = 'http://www.domain.extension/folder?schnoo=schnok&foo=bar'
parsed_url = URI.parse(url)
new_url = parsed_url.scheme+"://"+parsed_url.host+parsed_url.path
```

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your goal. Do you want extract parameters from request in your controller?

Comment: Is this the URL from the current request, or just a completely arbitrary URL?

Comment: You need to add port if present (and other than 80):
`new_url = "#{parsed_url.scheme}://#{parsed_url.host}#{parsed_url.port != 80 ? (':'+parsed_url.port) : ''}#{parsed_url.path}"`

Comment: @hammady - `+parsed_url.port` won't work without explicit converting to string first. Use `+parsed_url.port.to_s` instead.

Comment: @silverdr that's right, didn't test it, should be `(':'+parsed_url.port.to_s)`

Comment: The OP asks "is there a _faster_ way to do this" -- I think maybe the answer is "no"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 url = 'http://www.domain.extension/folder?schnoo=schnok&foo=bar'
 u = URI.parse(url)
 p = CGI.parse(u.query)
 # p is now {"schnoo"=>["schnok"], "foo"=>["bar"]}
```

Take a look on the : [how to get query string from passed url in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316656/how-to-get-query-string-from-passed-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 17):

Easier to read and harder to screw up if you parse and set `fragment` & `query` to `nil` instead of rebuilding the URL.

```
parsed = URI::parse("http://www.domain.extension/folder?schnoo=schnok&foo=bar#frag")
parsed.fragment = parsed.query = nil
parsed.to_s

# => "http://www.domain.extension/folder"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can gain performance using Regex

```
'http://www.domain.extension/folder?schnoo=schnok&foo=bar'[/[^\?]+/]

#=> "http://www.domain.extension/folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably no need to split the url. When you visit this link, you are pass two parameters to back-end:

`http://www.domain.extension/folder?schnoo=schnok&foo=bar`
`params[:schnoo]=schnok`
`params[:foo]=bar`

Try to monitor your log and you will see them, then you can use them in controller directly.