# Rails how to get id from current url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-record-query

I am building application – simple grade book and got stuck in one thing. I have model files for User, Grade and Test where:

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :test
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :grade, dependent: :destroy
   validates :topic, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :grades, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Grade table contains user_id, test_id and result.

The idea is this: Each User from user#show page can go only to his/her grades from certain subject (I made only two). Teacher can see grades of every created student. And here is the thing: when I'm logged as teacher (admin) and going from certain User page to Grades page my URL changes like this:

`/user/7`  -> `/grades/7?subject=History`

For User’s id everything is clear but in my DB, I don’t have Grade with id=7. So question is this:

How can I access this id ‘7’ from grade link to compare it with user_id in Grade table to display grades of this user only. Tried like below, but got empty table:

```
<% @grades.each do |g| %>
    <tr>
        <% if Test.find(g.test_id).subject == 'History' && User.find(params[:id]) == g.user_id %>
            <td><%= Test.find(g.test_id).topic %></td> 
            <td><%= Test.find(g.test_id).date %>
            <td><%= g.result %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

So generally I am looking for something like `this_url(params[:id])`. Do you have any ideas? Please help!

Comment: check the `params` variable and access what you need

Comment: Please paste the link that generates the URI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I'll advice is to have as little logic as possible on your view.

That being said: If you want to get the grades of a particular user, since grades has a relationship with users, you should be able to just call `user.grade` directly.

Also, you don't need to do `<%= Test.find(g.test_id).topic %>` in your view, instead of calling `Test.find(g.test_id).topic`, you can just call `g.test.topic`.

So, to give a total refactor, you can have the following in your controller:

```
def <the name of your controller action>
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @grades = @user.grades.where(subject: 'history')
end
```

and then in your view:

```
<% @grades.each do |g| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= g.test.topic %></td> 
    <td><%= g.test.date %>
    <td><%= g.result %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and everything should work just fine.

**Note:** *you can [follow this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316656/how-to-get-query-string-from-passed-url-in-ruby-on-rails) to get the name of your subject from the URL and include it dynamically into your controller query, but I will advise to pass the subject as a params as well ( `/grades/7/history` ), as opposed to passing it as a query ( `/grades/7?subject=History` ).*

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I was looking for.