# Rails 4 Error: How to get parameters from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url, parameters

I am fairly new to rails and I am struggling getting the id param out of this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=13
```

Currently I am using this line of code to get it:

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

This line directs to that:

```
redirect_to "/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=#{@job.id}"
```

Any help on how to achieve what I am trying to do is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
replace this line

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

with this line

```
@job = Job.find_by(id: params[:job_id])
```

and you will get your instance variable @job populated with the record which having job_id.

Comment: Yep, that really should work. But when I am doin this I get this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SubscriberjobsController#update
Couldn't find Job with 'id'=` so it somehow misses it's id in that case: `13`

Comment: This is the case where record is not present in your db/table. what you getting? when hitting params

Comment: I think I know why this does not work. From my new_job form it jumps to this url: `http://localhost:3000/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=13`. Then after you done the payments it directs to this url: `http://localhost:3000/subscriberjobs/1` (which does not work cause this model does not exist) and then checks for the `job_id` wich is obviously equal to nil

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
url    = 'http://www.foo.com?id=4&empid=6'
uri    = URI.parse(url)
params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
# params is now {"id"=>["4"], "empid"=>["6"]}

id     = params['id'].first
```

You may check another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316656/how-to-get-query-string-from-passed-url-in-ruby-on-rails) for more description.

Comment: Hmmm... that spits out this error: `NoMethodError in SubscriberjobsController#update
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Additionally it makes `"id"=>"1"}` out of every id

Comment: Then you need to check if the record exists in the database.

Comment: One thing though. Everytime it jumps to /subscriberjobs/1 after the payment via stripe. The record exists in Jobs