# Sending a POST request from a GET-structured URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, post

I have GET-type URLs with the parameters at the end of the URL string. I need to restructure them so that the stuff before the `?` becomes the endpoint and the stuff after gets sent out as parameters in a correctly-formatted POST request payload.

For example:

```
http://ecample.com?test=true&message=hello
```

needs to be sent out as a POST request to the URL `http://example.com` with a request payload of:

```
{"test":true,"message":"hello"}
```

Any ideas or quick tricks to get this so I can get the POST response?

Comment: You can use GET style parameters as you have here, and simply change your action in the form from a GET to a POST

Comment: "Sent out as post request" by browser or by the server? Check out [URI::Parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Parser.html#method-i-parse) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990997/how-do-i-create-a-hash-from-a-querystring-in-ruby) as some places to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? It's easier to fix your code than it is to write a tutorial or code from scratch and it lets us know you have tried and aren't just asking for us to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meditate on this:

```
require 'uri'

scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment = URI.split('http://example.com?test=true&message=hello')

scheme # => "http"
userinfo # => nil
host # => "example.com"
port # => nil
registry # => nil
path # => ""
opaque # => nil
query # => "test=true&message=hello"
fragment # => nil

uri = URI.parse('http://example.com?test=true&message=hello')
server = '%s://%s' % [uri.scheme, uri.host] # => "http://example.com"
parameters = Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)] # => {"test"=>"true", "message"=>"hello"}
```

At this point you can use whatever you want to connect to the `server` and send the `parameters` using GET, POST or any of the other request types.

[URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) is built into Ruby and has all the methods necessary to take apart URLs correctly and rebuild them.

---

When learning a computer language, it's mandatory to read through all the libraries and become familiar with their offerings. I do it many times, not to know exactly where a particular method is and its parameters, but to remember that it exists somewhere and then I can search and find it. Any modern language that can talk to web services will have such functionality available to it; It's your job to read the documentation and become familiar with it.