# Extract params values from link, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have link like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/sms/receive/sms-id=7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab&operator-%20id=1&from=37126300682&to=371144&text=RV9+c+Dace+Reituma+0580913
```

I want to extract all diferent variable values from this link. For example sms-id,operator,from, to  and text.

So far I have like this:

**routes.rb**

```
get 'sms/receive/:params', to: 'sms#receive'
```

**SMS#RECEIVE controller**

```
def receive

     query = params[:params]

      sms_id=     query[/["="].+?[&]/]   

      flash[:notice] = sms_id

end
```

This gives me : `=7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab&` but I need without  the first = and last characher & .

If I try to add strings like :`query[/["sms-id"].+?[&operator]/]` that could allow me to extract all variables smoothly, it gives me error : `empty range in char class: /["sms-id"].+?[&operator]/`

But I believe there is other way to extract all these variable values in different way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your regular expression is because the `-` is a reserved character when in-between square brackets. In this context, it must be escaped with a backslash: `\-`.

To parse your query string, you can do this:

```
sms_id = params[:params].match(/sms-id=([^&]*)/)[1]
```

or parse it with the more generic method:

```
parsed_query = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(params[:params])
sms_id = parsed_query['sms-id']
```

(quoted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2775086/2387219))

If you have control over the initial URL, change the last `/` for a `?` for an even easier solution:

```
http://localhost:3000/sms/receive?sms-id=7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab&operator-%20id=1&from=37126300682&to=371144&text=RV9+c+Dace+Reituma+0580913
```

and you will have `sms-id` in `params`:

```
sms_id = params['sms-id']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
get 'sms/receive/', to: 'sms#receive'
```

path in `routes.rb` and get `params` in the controller

Comment: This gives me `No route matches [GET] "/sms/receive/sms-id=7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab&operator-%20id=1&from=37126300682&to=371144&text=RV9+c+Dace+Reituma+0580913"` I tried this before...

Comment: Can you change url to correct syntax: "/sms/receive?sms-id=7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab&operator-%20id=1&f‌​rom=37126300682&to=371144&text=RV9+c+Dace+Reituma+0580913" (add ? instead of / before params)?

Comment: Nice one, I understand my problem now. I can access all params except sms-id and operator-id, because that line in midle should be in underscore ?

Comment: Should probabluly note that query string (stuff after `?`) is **not** part of the route and should not be mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
matches = params[:params].scan(/(?:=)([\w\+]+)(?:\&)?/)
# this will make matches = [[first_match], [second_match], ..., [nth_match]]

# now you can read all matches

sms_id = matches[0][0]
operator_id = matches[1][0]
from = matches[2][0]
to = matches[3][0]
text = matches[4][0]
# and it will not contatin = or &
```

I suggest for you to make method in model or helper, and not to write whole code in controller.

Comment: Looks good but when I tried I got error  `undefined method `scan' `

Comment: What type is `params[:params]` it has to be string